# Help recovering grub dual-boot functionality after driver and system (linux) upgrade. What can I do?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, winusb

I need help. I have a Windows 10 Single Language and also a Ubuntu 16.04.2 on dual boot (legacy). Installation went well at first, resizing a partition also went well to get space for Linux. Also, Grub worked nicely at first booting both operating systems. What I did later destroyed Windows 10 boot. I just installed ROS Kinect and also the nvidia driver. Then I had the brilliant idea to run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade. To my surprise I saw grub being upgraded and writing boot info again (fear & tears in my eyes...). Booted once more then Windows 10 stopped booting. Now the screen seems to present video driver or display problems (diagonally spaced parallel glitched lines).

The only thing I tried was to reinstall linux from scratch, and use the nomodeset stuff in the grub config... none worked.

The current situation is. I cannot boot Windows, only Linux (which I think is not using proprietary nvidia drivers, instead it seems to be using Intel HD video driver now). Even reinstalling Windows from Image does not work with a USB device because the app I am using (winusb) for this purpose only generates boot devices for UEFI config (I am using legacy), so install fails (missing drivers: after booting Windows when UEFI is enabled at the bios, doesn't even boot if legacy is enabled at the BIOS, displaying a message like: missing normal boot cfg). What I need help with:

1. Restore proper boot using Grub for Windows 10 (if the problem is a grub config). I suspect this is video/card driver config.
2. If 1 fails. Help me create a bootable USB with Windows 10 image inside linux that boots both UEFI and Legacy configs. I already downloaded & installed winusb (after some research on how to get it from xenial & also error 256 from gui, it is now working from command line, though booting only from UEFI mode).
3. If everything else fails, what can I do to reinstall everything making sure I am not going to lose both OSs?

Any actual help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that I notice is that you must have changed your BIOS from UEFI to Legacy. Why? Windows 10 was probably installed in UEFI mode, and you'd want to install Ubuntu the same way. Also, how did you resize your Windows partition to make room for Ubuntu?

Comment: I installed both OSs in legacy mode. Recall that they were both working in dual-boot at first, with legacy config.

Comment: Yes. Resizing to make room for Ubuntu.

Comment: Also I tried to install everything again with UEFI, but the usb boot disk I created complains of missing Windows drivers (so I gave up on that)

Comment: Do you have a DVD drive on your system? If so, burn a Ubuntu Live DVD instead of a USB and I think things will go better. Set your BIOS back to UEFI, wipe the hard drive (assuming that you've got stuff backed up), and reinstall Windows 10 first, then Ubuntu.

Comment: Does it make a difference if it is DISK or USB? I have UBUNTU on another stick... I do have a DVD drive, trying to get a disk though.

Comment: I've seen too many problems when using a USB stick, and using a DVD seems to always work. Make sure that you init the disk with GPT/GUID partition table using gparted before trying to reinstall OS's (and set UEFI in the BIOS first).

Comment: Just to let you know... because I'm lucky. The stick I created for Windows 10 works for UEFI, but complains about driver failure. Apparently, the one I created for Ubuntu works for Legacy only BIOS. This is just really annoying. Sigh, I have been using Linux for 20 years.... and for 20 years dual-boot seems experimental. Awesome. I have wiped out the drive as you suggested... still doesn't seem to work set BIOS to UEFI and install Windows 10 from scratch. So, I decided to just keep Ubuntu. that is just really disappointing, but I cannot wait.

Comment: If you're installing any custom drivers in Windows, then you might have to turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem wiping out the hdd and installing ONLY UBUNTU. Avoid grub, avoid installing from stick, and if you can, avoid dual-boot.